# Fundamental equation of thermodynamics for magnetocaloric materials

Tags: thermodynamics, magnetism

The fundamental equation of thermodynamics, as us chemists (and chemical engineers!) are used to seeing it, is

$$ dG = - S~dT + V~dP + \sum_{i}\mu_i~dN_i$$

This gives the Gibbs free energy as a function of temperature, pressure, and composition, *assuming there are no other relevant forces other than mechanical pressure*.

The other day I watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJ_NpWnCXzM) on the [magnetocaloric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration).  Obviously, there are non-pressure magnetic forces acting in such systems.  **What's the proper form of the fundamental equation for magnetocaloric materials?**

Suppose that the magnetocaloric material used is chemically pure and non-reactive during the magnetization process.  Then we could get rid of the $\sum_{i}\mu_i~dN_i$ term.  I suppose its also reasonable to assume that pressure is constant during magnetization / demagnetization process, and that the volume of the material is unchanged by magnetization so probably we could dispense with the $V~dP$ term as well (is that true?).

That leaves us with $dG = -S~dT + \rm{MAGNETIC~STUFF}$.  The $\rm{MAGNETIC ~STUFF}$ term probably has a $B$ or $H$ or something like that in it to represent the imposed magnetic field, but what else goes in there?

Comment: A quick google search led me to [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.64.144406). Maybe it has the answer you are looking for. I cannot access the paper from my home.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- it is definitely relevant.  Since I'm not a physicist, it's tough going for me, but if I am able to make enough sense of it over the next few days, I might submit an answer to my own question.  It seems like they use $H$ in their treatment, so I guess the right term in the equation would either be $x dH$ or $H dx$, but I still don't know what $x$ is or should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental equation for paramagnetic system is as follows
$$dU=TdS+BdM+\mu dN$$
Where B is the external magnetic field intensity and M is the magnetic moment (Here I have neglected the P-V work of the system). For your chemically pure and non-reactive system the above equation simplifies to
$$dU=TdS+BdM$$
Using Legendre Transformations:
$$y(0)=U(S,M)$$
$$dy(0)=dU=TdS+BdM$$
$$dy(1)=dA(T,M)=-SdT+BdM$$
$$dy(2)=dG(T,B)=-SdT-MdB$$ 
Now changing the order of the equation, we can find enthalpy,
$$y(0)=U(M,S)$$
$$dy(0)=dU=BdM+TdS$$
$$dy(1)=dH(S,B)=-MdB+TdS$$

Comment: Is M the magnetic moment or the [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization)?   If the latter, it seems like in SI units it has units of Amperes per meter, or (dividing by Faraday's constant) moles per second per meter, and B has units of kg per second per Coulomb, or kg per second per mole.  Then the magnetic force term has units of $kg/s^{2}/m$, which could also be written as Joules per cubic meter.  But don't the other terms in the equation have units of Joules, or at least Joules per mol?

Comment: M is magnetic moment while magnetization is density of magnetic moment. For dimensional consistency, B=intensity of magnetic field (Tesla or T), M=Magnetic moment (J/T). So, $B \times M = J ~or~ J/mol $ in terms of per mol basis